# How can I use get data from a camera using the I2C and Arduino or Raspberry-pi 3?

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, video-streaming, i2c

I have a [CMOS camera](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11745) and it just has 3 pins (v+,gnd and video out), the video output is an analog signal.
Doing some rechearch, I find that this camera uses a [PC1089K](http://www.datasheetspdf.com/PDF/PC1089K/925068/3) CMOS sensor, whish has a digital output and an I2C connection used to communicate with a Serial EEPROM memory ( a AT24C16K chip).
I located the I2C pins, and I need to know if I can use Arduino or Raspberry-pi to get the data from the camera so I can send the video stream over Xbee.

Comment: haven't I already told you to get a digital camera a few weeks ago?
EEPROMs on cameras usually serve only one purpose. to store parameters like shutter time, gain, ip adresse and so on. see answer below.

Comment: yes you did, I just can't afford a new camera right now, the price is expensive in my country. But since I spend a lot of time in vain working with this camera, I think it's time to figure out how to buy a new camera :).
So thank you @Piglet

Answer (score 6):

Short answer? Absolutely not. It is practically impossible to send video data through a low bandwidth connection (like the I2C) without a dedicated hardware compressor.

The reason? I2C maximum clock speed is 400kHz. Let's say that every byte is sent in 10 clock cycles (it is a bit more, since you have to send out also the address, but anyway...). This means 40kB/s. Let's say you are coding each pixel with only one byte (VERY poor, it's the 256 colors setting, see for instance [this image](http://www.ximagic.com/q_im_kodim23_256/kodim23_256_unif332.png)). You have 40k pixels per second. A proper video speed is 25 frames per second, but let's go down to 1 frame per second (you will see ONE image every second, like whn you open low quality cam view). so every image is 40k pixels. This means a frame about 240x180. So you have a VERY little view (smaller than the worst image setting in youtube), with one picture per second, with only 256 colors and that is the best you can achieve in the best conditions... Well, no, you definitely can't.

Moreover when you are in doubt, read the manual (or in the electronics field, the datasheet). You can find it [here](http://www.datasheetspdf.com/PDF/PC1089K/925068/4), for instance.

You can see that the I2C interface is labelled as master (this means that the camera OWNS the bus) and, reading a bit more, you will find that the only usage for this is to allow the user (or designer) to put an I2C EEPROM to provide initialization values for the registers.

So, the only way to get the video from your camera is through the analog port. There is no other interface, nor you can use a low bandwidth channel (like I2C or even the XBee one) without a compression.

Now, if you have to transmit video wirelessly I suggest you to, in order of preference,

1. Get a wifi camera
2. Get a Raspicam and a raspberry and share the video on a wifi link
3. Same as above, but with a USB webcam instead of the raspicam
4. ...
5. ...
6. Give up on this project
7. ...
8. Use raspicam or usb, raspberry and a Xbee (raspberry should compress the video a lot, for instance with h264 or, if the cpu can, h265)
9. Use the cmos sensor you have with a USB video acquisition peripheral and a raspberry, then compress the video and use wifi or... No, at least not the xbee

Comment: the sensor has digital output. although I must admit that someone who asks such questions like that won't have the skills to utilize that any time soon. and the effort isn't worth it in 2017

Comment: @frarugi87 thank you for the informations, I think that I need a new camera.